# How can I record the script of Login page with multiple users( Different session id) in JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

I have just started to learn JMeter with recording scripting, but which I have not got a proper result of the Login with multiple users login because of the session id, Please suggest to me a proper way to record the script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your test plan screenshot. For multiple user it require to config CSV.

Comment: How can I configure CSV, can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Please check steps for CSV config : https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config

Comment: Use 'recording' in template from JMeter File menu>Templates.
After recording, use following article to configure login requests.. https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743663-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record a script for single user then pass the CSV data to the script and configure no of user in Thread.

1. Record a Script of Login in.
2. Create a CSV with of 2 columns username and password
3. Create CSV data config by right clicking on Thread.

[image]

4. Provide filename of csv, In variables name give `username,password`
5. In delimiter add `,`

[image]

6. Then add the variable's name in your sampler.

[image]

Make sure you add number of users in Thread

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For session ID management I would use [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://techcrunch.com/2015/12/16/brazils-congress-has-shut-down-whatsapp-tonight-and-the-rest-of-the-social-web-could-be-next/?ncid=rss&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Techcrunch%20%28TechCrunch%29)

If your sessions are cookie based then I would suggest [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)